# Crystal report print minimum of 20 lines on each page

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to print minimum of 20 lines on each page on Crystal Report.
If report has only 1 line in detail data, it needs to print 19 empty lines with line number on the page (number 1 to 20). I found this solution in the internet but doesn't work for me. I placed it on format formula on details:

```
if Remainder(Recordnumber,20)=0 then
    true
else
    false
```

I am using Crystal Reports 9

Comment: In case of Crystal Reports you would really have to remove the white spaces from the details section.

Comment: Two possibilities. 1) create 20 detail sections with constant line numbers and show-hide them properly 2) use and link to helper table to actually have 20 lines for each report group.

Comment: I have created 20 detail sections and wrote formula to supress each of them.. It is not an easy task. might be wrong.Is thare any easy way to do this task. Rather than creating aditonal detail sections and hiding them